# CSS media-query at 400px isn't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Can someone tell me how to fix this media query issue.. https://jsfiddle.net/1z8sw4n5/19/

```
  .clear { clear: none; display: none; }
```

I want at 400px to hide content column without breaking the yellow right float so blue and yellow touch seamlessly and hide red @400px or less

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* The code you want debugged should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is that the width of #left and #right are both 200px. When the browser is less than 400px the divs are forced to stack. If you set the width on both of them to 50% and use `float: left` then they can sit next to each other.
You will also need to create a media query for #right and move the original #right css to above the media queries.

Here's a fix...

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyQVeg?editors=1100

Comment: That mostly works but for me in chrome as I get to 400 it wraps or breaks the div so its no longer visible. Can you tweak codepen to make it work at min res or below?

Comment: @PeterHerz He provided a working codepen and an explanation of what was the problem. What would you behave to behave differently?